# How to figure out that given point is inside the rectangle or not

Tags: ipad

i am working on app in which i want to draw an Rectangle.for draw a rectangle i have two CGRECT point.after draw a rectangle i have to pass a point and check whether the given point is lying inside the rectangle or not.can someone help me.Thanks

```
-(void)touchBeganAtPoint:(CGPoint)point{

    if (isDrawingCompleted) {        
        match = NSNotFound;

        for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [pointArray count]; i++)
        {
            NSValue *touchPointValue = [pointArray objectAtIndex:i];
            CGPoint currentPoint = [touchPointValue CGPointValue];
            CGRect controlPointRect = [self controlPointRectForPoint:currentPoint];

            if (CGRectContainsPoint(controlPointRect, point))
            {
                match = i;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

point is the variable which i have to check lie inside the rectangle which will make with two point store in point array.point array have always two point.

Comment: What do you mean by `CGRect points`? Do you mean the points that define the corners of a CGRect?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`CGRectContainsPoint`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint).

```
bool CGRectContainsPoint (
   CGRect rect,
   CGPoint point
);
```

Comment: can you guide me how to design REctangle with two given CGRECT point

Answer (score 0):

Use [CGRectContainsPoint](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html) function

Comment: Thanks Vladimir. actually i have tried but it check the given point in between two CGRECT POINT. can you give me idea how to draw an rectangle with the help of two CGRECT POint.